# VideoJS Playlist UI on Fullscreen

Tags: html5-video, video.js, playlist

Is it possible for VideoJS to show/hide the playlist when in fullscreen? I've looked for examples online including even with the VideoJS based Brightcove's player and not found any so far. An example of the Playlist UI is: https://videojs.com/advanced/

I am looking to migrate from the MediaElementJS player which does support toggling the playlist from fullscreen, to VideoJS if i can get its playlist behaving in a similar manner. Exiting fullscreen to use the playlist is not acceptable.

If this functionality isn't currently supported, does anyone know any way around this issue? Perhaps an iframe based solution to keep the player fullscreen while accessing the playlist?

I'm not a web dev so please provide detailed info and/or full code examples rather than snippets. I'm getting there gradually.

Thanks!

Comment: No ideas anyone?